# Search with partial regex and partial non-regex search text in another string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, search

I have two files:

```
efile = c:\myexternal.txt    
cfile = c:\mycurrent.txt
```

myexternal.txt:

```
Paris
London
Amsterdam
New York
```

mycurrent.txt (but it can be whatever text):

```
Paris is a city in France
A city in the UK is London
In the USA there is no city named Manchester
Amsterdam is in the Netherlands
```

What I want to do is for every line in externalfile (raw text) do a search in the current file but with regex boundaries :

p.e.:
I want to find all cities from externalfile in currentfile but not the cities with "is " before and all cities must have space after the cityname or must be at end of line:

```
boundO = "(?<!is\s)"
boundC = "(?=\s|$)"
#boundO + line in externalfile + boundC
#(regex rawtext regex)

#put every line of external file (c:\myexternal.txt) in list:
externalfile=[]
with open(efile, 'r+', encoding="utf8") as file:
  for line in file:
      if line.strip():                 #if line != empty
          line=line.rstrip("\n")       #remove linebreaks
          line=boundO + line + boundC  #add regex bounderies
          externalfile.append(line)

results = []
#check every line in c:\mycurrent.txt
with open(cfile, 'r+', encoding="utf8") as file:
  for line in file:
      if any(ext in line for ext in externalfile):
          results.append(line)
```

This does not work:
The boundaries are not seen as regex.

What did I wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by _boundaries are not seen as regex_?

Comment: @rock321987, The text in the external file must be raw text.. p.e. if '\' is in the external file, this character must be seen as '\" and not as a backslash in regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html#re.search) instead of the `in` operator:

```
if any(re.search(ext, line) for ext in externalfile):
```

And, to prevent the text from the file to be interpreted as regex, use [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html#re.escape):

```
line= boundO + re.escape(line) + boundC  #add regex bounderies
```

Comment: This does work. Regex is seen as regex, text as text. Thank you very much! But it is very very slow. If I don't use re.search but my `if any(ext in line for ext in externalfile)` it takes 2 seconds. If I use your method it takes over 4 minutes. [With an external file of 8000 lines and currentfile with 900 lines]. Do you know I way to do it faster?

Comment: @Reman To speed it up you could combine regex and string operations like so: `if any(ext in line and re.search(boundO + re.escape(ext) + boundC, line) for ext in externalfile):`.

Comment: Are you sure? That doesn't give any match in my file.

Comment: @Reman You have to remove the `line= boundO + re.escape(line) + boundC` line for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need `re.search`. Use

```
with open("check.pl", 'r+') as file:
    for line in file:
        if any(re.search(ext, line) for ext in externalfile): # <---here
            print(line)
            results.append(line)
```

**Output**

```
Paris is a city in France

Amsterdam is in the Netherlands
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

**EDIT**

I am not sure but, check this

```
boundO = "(?<!is\s)\\b"
boundC = "(?=\s|$)"
#boundO + line in externalfile + boundC
#(regex rawtext regex)

#put every line of external file (c:\myexternal.txt) in list:
externalfile=[]
with open("check", 'r+') as file:
  for line in file:
      if line.strip():                 #if line != empty
          line=line.rstrip("\n")       #remove linebreaks
          #line=boundO + line + boundC  #add regex bounderies
          externalfile.append(line)

results = []
print(externalfile)
#check every line in c:\mycurrent.txt
with open("check.pl", 'r+') as file:
    for line in file:
        if any(re.search(boundO + ext + boundC, line) for ext in externalfile):
            print(line)
            results.append(line)
```

Comment: It is important that the lines in the external files are not seen as regex, only the boundaries. (btw Manchester is also a match)

Comment: @Reman How can `Manchestar` be a match when its not in first file?

Comment: @Reman what do you mean exactly by  _external files are not seen as regex, only the boundaries._

Comment: You're right Manchester is not a match. - The text in the external file must be raw text.. p.e. if '\' is in the external file, this character must be seen as '\" and not as a backslash in regex.

Comment: yes, city names is just an example. External file can contain all type of text.

Comment: rock321987, `any(re.search(boundO + ext + boundC, line)` does enter in a infinity loop

Answer (score 1):

regex needs to be compiled before be used.

```
ext in line
```

will only test if the string ext can be found in line

You should use something like following instead :

```
import re
regc=re.compile(ext)
regc.search(line)
```

Comment: This is not the whole code you need, but only a part that what missing in your code. Import re at the beginning, then insert re.compile and regc.search where ext is defined in your code. For performance reasons, if your files are big, you should compile and store every regex first before looping over mycurrent.txt lines.